# Insert the data in the database

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I need to add data to the database, they are not being added
My DatabaseHelper

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLDataException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "nedb.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException {
        if (mNeedUpdate) {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            mNeedUpdate = true;
    }
    public Boolean checkloginpass(String log, String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Пользователь where Логин =? AND Пароль =?", new String[]{log, pass});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public Boolean insertData(String login, String password, String im, String Poc, String np){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Почта", Poc);
        values.put("Имя", im);
        values.put("Номер_Телефона", np);
        values.put("Логин", login);
        values.put("Пароль", password);

        long result = db.insert("Пользователь", null, values);
        if(result == 1) return false;
        else return true;

    }
    public Boolean checkuser(String login){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Пользователь where Логин =?", new String[]{login});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public Boolean checkuserandpass(String login, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Пользователь where Логин =? AND Пароль =?", new String[]{login, password});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public Boolean UpdateDataUser(String login, String im, String Poc, String np){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Почта", Poc);
        values.put("Имя", im);
        values.put("Номер_Телефона", np);
        values.put("Логин", login);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Пользователь where Логин =?", new String[]{login});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            long result = db.update("Пользователь", values, "Логин =?", new String[]{login});
            if (result == -1){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

My add activity

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.*;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class RegActivity extends Activity {
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        try {
            mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
        }

        try {
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        Button btn_r = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reg);
        TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
        EditText editTextLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        EditText editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        EditText editTextMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mail);
        EditText editTextNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number);

        btn_r.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getLogin = editTextLogin.getText().toString();
                String getPass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String getName = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String getNumber = editTextNumber.getText().toString();
                String getMail = editTextMail.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(getLogin) || TextUtils.isEmpty(getPass)){
                    tx1.setText("123");
                }
                else{
                    if(editTextPassword != editTextLogin){
                        Boolean chekuser = mDBHelper.checkuser(getLogin);
                        if(chekuser == false) {
                            Boolean insert = mDBHelper.insertData(getLogin, getPass, getName, getMail, getNumber);
                            if (insert == true) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void OnClickBackToMain(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Nothing appears in the database after registration, but I can log in using this data. But after restarting the application, I can no longer log in using this data. Please help, I will be very grateful, thank you in advance.
My AuthorizationActivity

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper DB;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db = DB.getWritableDatabase();


        Button btn_s = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sig);
        Button btnpro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_pro);
        TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
        EditText editTextLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);


        btn_s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getLogin = editTextLogin.getText().toString();
                String getPass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(getLogin) || TextUtils.isEmpty(getPass)){
                    int a = 0;
                }
                else{
                    Boolean cup = DB.checkloginpass(getLogin, getPass);
                    if(cup == true){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In insertData method you have written like this

```
if(result == 1) return false;
    else return true;
```

db.insert will return -1 if insert operation fails and will return the row id if the insertion succeeds. I believe, insertion is succeeding and data is getting saved. That's why login is working.  You can change the code to

```
if(result == -1) return false;
        else 
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem is that data is not being added to the table.

Comment: How do you know data is not inserted? Did you query after insertion or tried with debug?  Can you check whether database is getting created again when you restart application? Also there is a mistake in comparing if(editTextPassword != editTextLogin). It will return false since it is comparing edit text and not the value in edit text. This is not related to your issue but just informing so that you can take of usecases. It will be better to use singleton pattern for databasehelper class.